# How to embed an external widget to a page in Bolt?

Tags: bolt-cms

I'm trying to embed a booking system widget to my bolt homepage (the one and only `homepage`, using base-2018 theme). I paste it into the `Content` window, selecting `Source` first. Bolt seems to interpret what is going on, as various tags and IDs are highlighted in the code.

The widget code is roughly so:

```
<div id="bokun [blabla]">Loading...</div>
<p><script type="text/javascript"><br />
var w15;<br />
(function(d, t) {<br />
  var host = 'widgets.bokun.io';<br />
  var frameUrl = 'https://' + host + '/widgets/15';<br />
  var s = d.createElement(t), options = {'host': host, 'frameUrl': frameUrl, 'widgetHash':'w15', 'autoResize':true,'height':'','width':'100%', 'minHeight': 0,'async':true, 'ssl':true, 'affiliateTrackingCode': '', 'transientSession': true, 'cookieLifetime': 43200 };<br />
  s.src = 'https://' + host + '/assets/javascripts/widgets/embedder.js';<br />
  s.onload = s.onreadystatechange = function() {<br />
    var rs = this.readyState; if (rs) if (rs != 'complete') if (rs != 'loaded') return;<br />
    try {<br />
      w15 = new BokunWidgetEmbedder(); w15.initialize(options); w15.display();<br />
    } catch (e) {}<br />
  };<br />
  var scr = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0], par = scr.parentNode; par.insertBefore(s, scr);<br />
})(document, 'script');<br />
</script></p>
```

I have only edited out the unique ID this widget has. Otherwise, this is copied from the provider and works on my current Wordpress site...ALTHOUGH when I paste it into Wordpress, the editor notifies me that "there's something wrong" and offers me to correct it.

How do I insert this? Do I need to create a .js file and reference it in compliance with Twig standards and if so, how do I? I should also note that the widget will redirect to a different page within the same site once you press something within it. Thank you.

Bolt version: `3.6.5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add every [tag and attribute that you need into the `config.yml](https://docs.bolt.cm/3.6/fields/html#input-sanitisation).

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I added `script` to `allowed_tags` and `text/javascript, text, javascript, bokun_[identifier]` to `allowed_attributes`. I had to save the homepage again, for Bolt to process the HTML according to new rules.

Comment: Or you can use a textarea field and bypass the filter

Comment: Would I then just put a <textarea> block around the widget? How does that work?